# Adding additional date to fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

am wondering if anyone has added a 2nd date to fullCalendar - for example adding the Hebrew date to the standard English one?
The Hebrew date (or any other) might be able to obtained via [Keith Wood's calendar script](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html)

thanks in advance

Comment: If you go to Fullcalendar documentation [link]http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/ you can set monthNames etc in calendar initialization.

Comment: thanks. maybe i wasnt clear - my question though isnt about the *translation* of the Georgian calendar, but rather about adding the lunar calendar to the Georgian one.